# Accessing FORM values as array

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a form that allows a user to create their own surveys. Each survey has `n` number of questions, and `n` number of answers per question.

For example (Not tested this form, just an example):

```
<form action="/add-survey" method="POST">
    <label for="question_1">Question 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="question[]">

    <ul id="answers">
        <li class="answer">
            <label for="answer_1">Answer 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="...."> /* What do I do here? */
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, in the PHP script I would like to access the forms like so:

```
$_POST['question'][0]['answer'][0] // Question 1, answer 1
```

If I set the `name` attribute to `answer[]` I end up with two arrays `question` and `answer`, which makes it difficult to work with.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this on your `answer input`

```
<input type="text" name="question[][answer][]">
```